# Safari rendering Google Font massive

Tags: html, css, fonts, safari, font-face

Hi there am having a problem with my navigation menu, it's using a link to Yanone Kaffeesatz via Google Fonts and using 26pt and small caps - it looks fine in IE/FF and Chrome but just checked Safari and Iphone and the font-size is considerably larger - so much so that the menu adds a second line

I don't think it's a problem with default font size on Safari as other fonts look identical to other browsers.

Here is the CSS, any help would be much appreciated

```
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
ul {list-style: none;}
a {color: black; text-decoration: none; padding-bottom: 3px;}
a:visited {color: black;}

body {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 100%;
    background-color: #bab89b;
    background-image:url('http://xxx/assets/background.jpg');
    font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light, Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;

}

container {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#header {
    width: 900px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#photo {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-right: 80px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

#photo img {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    rotation: 90deg;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg) scale(0.9);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg) scale(0.9);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;

}       

#photo img:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg) scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform: rotate(10deg) scale(1.1);
}

#titles {float: left;}

#header h1 {
    font-family: Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 56pt;
    font-weight: 100;
    margin-top: 30px;

}

#header h2 {
    font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light, Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 20pt;
}

/* NAVIGATION */

#navWrap {
    width: 900px;
    height: 3em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding-top: 1em;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}

#nav {
    width: 900px;
}

#nav li {
    display: inline;
    line-height: 3em;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

#nav li a {
    font-family: Yanone Kaffeesatz, sans-serif;
    color: black;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-size: 26pt;
    margin-right: 40px;
    text-decoration: none;
}


#nav li a:hover {border-bottom: 4px solid black;}
#nav li a.current:hover {border-bottom: none;}

/* CONTENT */

#content {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#contentHeader {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

#contentHeader h2 {
    font-family: Helvetica Neue; Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24pt;
    font-weight: 100;
}


/* SUBJECTS PAGE */


#box1, #box2, #box3 {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    font-family: Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
}


.clearer {
    clear: both;

}

.leftContent {
    float: left;
    width: 480px;
    height: 240px;
    padding: 40px;
    border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;

}

.leftContent h3 {
    font-size: 22pt;
    font-weight: 100;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.leftContent h4 {
    font-size: 18pt;
    font-weight: 100;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}


.leftContent p {
    font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light, Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11pt;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.rightContent {
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
    height: 120px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 40px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    font-style: italic;
}

.rightContent h3 {
    font-size: 16pt;
    font-weight: 100;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.rightContent li {
    font-size: 11pt;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}



/* FEEDBACK */

.bubbleText {
    width: 550px;
    margin: 30px auto 5px auto;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light, Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: 300;
}


.bubbleDesc {
    margin-bottom: 
}

#showMoreLink, #showLessLink {
    margin-top: 40px;
    font-size: 24pt;
    font-style: italic;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#showMoreLink:hover, #showLessLink:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#moreText {
    display: none;
}

/* BIO */

#leftBioBlock {
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
    margin-right: 60px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

#rightBioBlock {
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
}

.bioTextBlock {
    font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
    width: 350px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto 50px auto;
    padding:30px;
    border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 15px; 
    border-radius: 15px;
    position: relative;
}

.bioTextBlockCenter {
    font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding:30px;
    border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 15px; 
    border-radius: 15px;

}

.bioTextBlockCenter:hover 

.bioTextBlock, .bioTextBlockCenter{
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 3px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 3px #888;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 3px #888;
}

.bioTextHead {
    font-size: 28pt;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.bioTextBlock p, bioTextBlock li, .bioList  {
    font-family: Helvetica Neue, Arial, Sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 11pt;
    line-height: 1.4em;
}

.bioList li {
    line-height: 2em;
}

#CVlink {
    position: absolute;
    left: 85px;
    bottom: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18pt;
    font-weight: 100;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.4s linear;
    -moz-transition: color 0.4s linear;
}

#CVlink:hover {
    color: #ce984e;
}

/* FORM */


form {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 40px;

}

legend {
    font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light, Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18pt;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    font-weight: 100;
}

label { 
     font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
     font-size: 16pt;
     display: block;
}

input, select { 
    width: 250px;
    height: 1.5em;
    font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light, Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12pt;
    color: #575754;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}


fieldset#formCol1 {
    width: 300px;
    padding: 25px;
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 80px;
    margin-left: 60px;
    vertical-align:top;
}

fieldset#formCol2{
    width: 300px;
    padding: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 37px;
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: top;
}


fieldset#formCol3 {
    clear: both;
    width: 740px;
    margin: 30px auto 0 60px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 25px;
}

select {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#sendButton {
    width: 80px;
}

textarea {
    width: 450px;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light, Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11pt;
}

placeholder {
    font-size: 11pt;
    font-style: italic;
}



#denotes {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-bottom: -20px;
    font-weight: 100;
}

/* HIDDEN SPAM TRAP BOX */

input.random {display: none;}


/* FOOTER */

#footer {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 100px auto 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    border-top: 1px dashed #666;
}

#footerCopy {
    font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light, Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-align: center;
}

.siteLink {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 28pt;
    font-weight: 100;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.8s linear;
    -moz-transition: color 0.8s linear;
}

.siteLink:hover {color: #ce984e; border-bottom: none;}

#profTutor {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14pt;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

/* IPHONE RULES */
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px), screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {


    div#rightContent1, div#rightContent2, div#rightContent3 {
        display: block;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use 26 px, not 26 pt. Points are intended for print, not screen display and will look different in each browser.

Comment: OK thanks have done that, I always thought pt was for fonts. Looking closely it seems that the other browsers are showing the Yanone font much more condensed whereas Safari is much wider. Have you seen this before? Thanks

Comment: Having looked around further I found this link [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014392/font-face-and-font-variant-bad-idea) which seems to point to a problem with font-variant and imported fonts being an issue in safari. When I remove font-variant all is normal again, yet unfortunately without the desired effect

Comment: I've never had problems with Safari font display; it's usually good. There might be a bug there though, as font-variant isn't exactly a commonly used property and being a CSS3 one, I'd bet it's not yet fully supported. But it's just a guess, so don't call me on that ;).

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your body

display: 0.99;

So the whole css will be

```
    * {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
    ul {list-style: none;}
    a {color: black; text-decoration: none; padding-bottom: 3px;}
    a:visited {color: black;}

    body {
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 100%;
        background-color: #bab89b;
        background-image:url('http://xxx/assets/background.jpg');
        font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light, Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
        display: 0.99;

    }

    container {
        width: 900px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #header {
        width: 900px;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #photo {
        float: left;
        margin-left: 80px;
        margin-right: 80px;
        margin-top: 30px;
    }

    #photo img {
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: #eee;
        border: 2px solid #ccc;
        rotation: 90deg;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg) scale(0.9);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg) scale(0.9);
        -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;

    }       

    #photo img:hover {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg) scale(1.1);
        -moz-transform: rotate(10deg) scale(1.1);
    }

    #titles {float: left;}

    #header h1 {
        font-family: Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 56pt;
        font-weight: 100;
        margin-top: 30px;

    }

    #header h2 {
        font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light, Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-style: italic;
        font-weight: 300;
        font-size: 20pt;
    }

    /* NAVIGATION */

    #navWrap {
        width: 900px;
        height: 3em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: 30px;
        padding-top: 1em;
        padding-bottom: 1em;
        border-top: 1px solid black;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #nav {
        width: 900px;
    }

    #nav li {
        display: inline;
        line-height: 3em;
        padding: 0 20px;
    }

    #nav li a {
        font-family: Yanone Kaffeesatz, sans-serif;
        color: black;
        font-variant: small-caps;
        font-size: 26pt;
        margin-right: 40px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }


    #nav li a:hover {border-bottom: 4px solid black;}
    #nav li a.current:hover {border-bottom: none;}

    /* CONTENT */

    #content {
        width: 900px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #contentHeader {
        width: 900px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: 40px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #contentHeader h2 {
        font-family: Helvetica Neue; Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 24pt;
        font-weight: 100;
    }


    /* SUBJECTS PAGE */


    #box1, #box2, #box3 {
        width: 900px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
        font-family: Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-weight: 100;
    }


    .clearer {
        clear: both;

    }

    .leftContent {
        float: left;
        width: 480px;
        height: 240px;
        padding: 40px;
        border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
        background-color: #e7e7e7;
        -moz-border-radius: 10px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 30px;

    }

    .leftContent h3 {
        font-size: 22pt;
        font-weight: 100;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .leftContent h4 {
        font-size: 18pt;
        font-weight: 100;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }


    .leftContent p {
        font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light, Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 11pt;
        line-height: 1.5em;
        font-weight: 300;
    }

    .rightContent {
        float: right;
        width: 200px;
        height: 120px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        padding: 40px;
        margin-top: 60px;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        font-style: italic;
    }

    .rightContent h3 {
        font-size: 16pt;
        font-weight: 100;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }

    .rightContent li {
        font-size: 11pt;
        font-weight: 100;
        line-height: 1.5em;
    }



    /* FEEDBACK */

    .bubbleText {
        width: 550px;
        margin: 30px auto 5px auto;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        background-color: #e7e7e7;
        -moz-border-radius: 15px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
        border-radius: 15px;
        padding: 20px 30px;
        font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light, Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 10pt;
        font-weight: 300;
    }


    .bubbleDesc {
        margin-bottom: 
    }

    #showMoreLink, #showLessLink {
        margin-top: 40px;
        font-size: 24pt;
        font-style: italic;
        font-variant: small-caps;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    #showMoreLink:hover, #showLessLink:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    #moreText {
        display: none;
    }

    /* BIO */

    #leftBioBlock {
        float: left;
        width: 400px;
        margin-right: 60px;
        margin-left: 20px;
    }

    #rightBioBlock {
        float: left;
        width: 400px;
    }

    .bioTextBlock {
        font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
        width: 350px;
        height: 300px;
        margin: 0 auto 50px auto;
        padding:30px;
        border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
        background-color: #e7e7e7;
        -webkit-border-radius: 15px; 
        -moz-border-radius: 15px; 
        border-radius: 15px;
        position: relative;
    }

    .bioTextBlockCenter {
        font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
        width: 400px;
        height: 300px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding:30px;
        border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
        background-color: #e7e7e7;
        -webkit-border-radius: 15px; 
        -moz-border-radius: 15px; 
        border-radius: 15px;

    }

    .bioTextBlockCenter:hover 

    .bioTextBlock, .bioTextBlockCenter{
        -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 3px #888;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 3px #888;
        box-shadow: 5px 5px 3px #888;
    }

    .bioTextHead {
        font-size: 28pt;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .bioTextBlock p, bioTextBlock li, .bioList  {
        font-family: Helvetica Neue, Arial, Sans-serif;
        font-weight: 300;
        font-size: 11pt;
        line-height: 1.4em;
    }

    .bioList li {
        line-height: 2em;
    }

    #CVlink {
        position: absolute;
        left: 85px;
        bottom: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 18pt;
        font-weight: 100;
        -webkit-transition: color 0.4s linear;
        -moz-transition: color 0.4s linear;
    }

    #CVlink:hover {
        color: #ce984e;
    }

    /* FORM */


    form {
        width: 900px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 40px;

    }

    legend {
        font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light, Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 18pt;
        padding-bottom: 15px;
        font-weight: 100;
    }

    label { 
         font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
         font-size: 16pt;
         display: block;
    }

    input, select { 
        width: 250px;
        height: 1.5em;
        font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light, Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12pt;
        color: #575754;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }


    fieldset#formCol1 {
        width: 300px;
        padding: 25px;
        display: inline;
        margin-right: 80px;
        margin-left: 60px;
        vertical-align:top;
    }

    fieldset#formCol2{
        width: 300px;
        padding: 25px;
        padding-bottom: 37px;
        display: inline;
        vertical-align: top;
    }


    fieldset#formCol3 {
        clear: both;
        width: 740px;
        margin: 30px auto 0 60px;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 25px;
    }

    select {
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }

    #sendButton {
        width: 80px;
    }

    textarea {
        width: 450px;
        height: 150px;
        padding: 5px;
        font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light, Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 11pt;
    }

    placeholder {
        font-size: 11pt;
        font-style: italic;
    }



    #denotes {
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: -20px;
        margin-bottom: -20px;
        font-weight: 100;
    }

    /* HIDDEN SPAM TRAP BOX */

    input.random {display: none;}


    /* FOOTER */

    #footer {
        width: 900px;
        margin: 100px auto 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 60px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        border-top: 1px dashed #666;
    }

    #footerCopy {
        font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light, Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 10pt;
        font-weight: 100;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .siteLink {
        text-align: center;
        font-family: Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 28pt;
        font-weight: 100;
        -webkit-transition: color 0.8s linear;
        -moz-transition: color 0.8s linear;
    }

    .siteLink:hover {color: #ce984e; border-bottom: none;}

    #profTutor {
        text-align: center;
        font-family: Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14pt;
        font-weight: 100;
        font-variant: small-caps;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    /* IPHONE RULES */
    @media screen and (max-device-width: 480px), screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {


        div#rightContent1, div#rightContent2, div#rightContent3 {
            display: block;
        }


    }
```